# Below data layout is moving up on setting display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a HTML/JS page. It has 2 containers- container1 and container2.

In container1, I have an Order Entry Form. And in container2, there are some other texts and images. In the view, container1 is on the top and container2 is on its bottom.

So what I am doing is in container1 - Upon successfully submitting of the Order Entry Form, it hides the Form and displays Order Confirmation Message in-place of Form. Below code is working good for me:

```
document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none'; // hide form
document.getElementById('confirmation_message').style.display = 'block'; //display confirmation message
```

Its hiding the form and displaying the confirmation message as expected.

But the **problem** I am facing is - after execution of above code, container2 data is also moving upwards and coming on container1 (just below the confirmation message).
Also to let know when I zoom in and Zoom out the page it automatically set the container2 data correctly on container2.
Could you please help what property I have missed.

Please check bookmywatercan.com. i have uploaded dummy demo page there. Fill the form and submit. Thank you mess will come then see the below content moved up. Please help. I need below content at the same place and container1 in organized form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, if you would like container2 to stay in the same place, you would need to set the `visibility` value to "hidden", rather than the `display` value to "none".

One of the differences between the two is that `visibility: hidden;` will maintain the elements place within the layout of the page, while `display: none;` will treat the element as if it does not even exist.

So try this instead, for the first line:

```
document.getElementById('form').style.visibility = 'hidden'; // hide form
```

Comment: Yes. Your are right talemyn. I want container2 data in the same place regardless of whatever will happen to container1.

I even tried visibility: hidden; but problem with this is it leaves a blank spaces. In my case, If I keep confirmation message is of 2-3 lines, and form is of 20-25 lines. So on first load it If I use visibility: hidden; for confirmation message it leaves a space of 2-3 lines and later on submitting the form when I use visibility: hidden; for form, it will leave empty space of 20-25 lines. It doesn't look good. I need to take only according to contents.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code in your question?  It will help to see the structure and types of elements that you are using.  You probably don't need to include all of the inputs in the form, if it is really long.   ;)

Comment: Please check bookmywatercan.com. i have uploaded dummy demo page there. Fill the form and submit. Thank you mess will come then see the below  content moved up. Please help. I need below content at the same place and container1 in organized form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access your site from my company's network . . . unless you can provide the code in you're question, I'll have to wait until later, to be able to look at it.

Comment: Ohh. Could you please tell me why my site is blocked ? I need to correct that also if any contents are blocked by firewalls by any ways; as i would like to make like a normal official site, Not entertaining which cant be accessed from company networks. It is like a single form page website only.

Comment: Anyways, i ll post the code soon. Give me sometime please. I ll get back.

Comment: LOL . . . don't get too worried about it . . . my company blocks a LOT of sites.  I'm sure it's nothing that you did.   :)